# Условные конструкции в предложениях безусловной семантики

Tags: грамматика, семантика

*(1) Если тебя назвали дураком, то меня нет.

(2) Если политики придумали противоестественное название государству, то на его граждан это не распространяется.

(3) Если вчера был дождь, то это не значит, что он будет сегодня.*

Какие из этих предложений правомерны с точки зрения грамматики? *Интересует только использование конструкции "если... то..." в данном контексте.*
Если такие есть, то как они называются? *Не "условные" же?*

Answer (score 1):

Все правомерны, это так называемые СПП с придаточными сопоставительными.

Формально такие предложения имеют придаточную часть, так как содержат подчинительные союзы (или союзные слова), однако по существу они приближаются к сложносочиненным предложениям, представляя собой случай переходный от подчинения к сочинению.

Две реально существующие ситуации соотносятся друг с другом по признакам различия или сходства, соответствия или несоответствия одна другой (АГ-80, с. 609, § 3094).Сопоставительные отношения оформляются союзами «если … то», «в то время как», «между тем как», «тогда как», «по мере того как», «чем ... тем,» «если ... то», «пускай ... зато», «коль скоро ... то»:

Если совершенства нет в природе, то ещё меньше его можно найти в искусстве и делах человека.

Если в дивизии и корпусе данные Травкина были восприняты как событие особой важности, то для штаба армии они имели уже хотя и важное, но вовсе не решающее значение (Казак.) - имеется подчинительный союз «если ... то»,однако функция его иная, чем в сложноподчиненных предложениях с придаточной условной: он утратил условное значение и используется в качестве чисто формального показателя объединения двух частей предложения, содержание которых сопоставляется. Формальное значение союза - как структурного показателя подчинённости в данном виде сопоставительных предложений подчёркивается, в частности, возможностью перемещения его из одной части предложения в другую. Ср.:

Если для штаба армии они [данные Травкина] имели уже хотя и важное, но вовсе не решающее значение, то в дивизии и корпусе данные Травкина были восприняты как событие особой важности.

Сложноподчиненное предложение с условной придаточной частью такого свободного перемещения союза не терпит. Кроме того, союз «если ... то» легко заменяется сочинительным союзом. Ср.:

В дивизии и корпусе данные Травкина были восприняты как событие особой важности, а (но) для штаба армии они имели уже хотя и важное, но вовсе не решающее значение.

(1)Тебя назвали дураком, а меня нет.
(2) Политики придумали противоестественное название государству, но на его граждан это не распространяется.
(3) Вчера был дождь, но это не значит, что он будет сегодня.